# How to expand a DateTimeIndex with some months before?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, time-series

I have a time-series corresponding to the end of the month for some dates of interest:

```
Date
31-01-2005  0.0
28-02-2006  0.0
30-06-2020  0.0
Name: Whatever, dtype: float64
```

I'd like to expand this dataframe's index with two month samples before each data point resulting in the following dataframe:

```
Date
30-11-2004  NaN
31-12-2004  NaN
31-01-2005  0.0
31-12-2005  NaN
31-01-2006  NaN
28-02-2006  0.0
30-04-2020  NaN
31-05-2020  NaN
30-06-2020  0.0
Name: Whatever, dtype: float64
```

How can I do that? Note that I am only interested in the resulting index.

My naive attempt was to do:

```
df.index.apply(lambda x: [x - pd.DateOffset(months=2), x - pd.DateOffset(months=1), x])
```

but index doesn't have an apply function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

```
idx =  [y for x in df.index for y in pd.date_range(x - pd.DateOffset(months=2), x, freq='M')]
df = df.reindex(pd.to_datetime(idx))
print (df)
            Whatever
2004-11-30       NaN
2004-12-31       NaN
2005-01-31       0.0
2005-12-31       NaN
2006-01-31       NaN
2006-02-28       0.0
2020-04-30       NaN
2020-05-31       NaN
2020-06-30       0.0
```